# Playing a sound in python is imp

Tags: python, audio

I am currently working on a project and wanted to add sound.

```
import playsound
x = "sound.mp3"
playsound.playsound(x, block=False)
```

but my code does not work.
The error it returns is:

```
Error 277 for command:
        open correct.mp3
    Fehler beim Starten von MCI.

    Error 263 for command:
        close correct.mp3
    Gerät ist nicht geöffnet oder wird vom MCI nicht erkannt.
Failed to close the file: correct.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\gui\TEMP TEMP TEMP.py", line 4, in <module>
    playsound.playsound(x, block=False)
  File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 72, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'open {}'.format(sound))
  File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 277 for command:
        open sound.mp3
    Fehler beim Starten von MCI.
```

All I can see is that it could not start "MCI" but I don't know what that is.
Ive also tried the following other methods to play sound:

- winsound
- pydub
  They did not work.
  The only thing that semi worked was using `os.system("start sound.mp3")` but it opened a seperate program to run it so its useless for me

Comment: try other modules, such as pymedia, mplayer.py, pyaudio, pympv.

Answer (score -3):

```py
#Go to online converter [ .mp3 to wav ] 

from playsound import playsound

playsound("C:\\Users\\ANURAG\\Music\\play.wav")
```

'''cause of this error is python 10 is not fully developed we are using pre-released version (playsound proper worked in python 8)'''